# Scroll Bar - Help

Tags: html, scrollbar

any one can help in this?, i want to make a scroll bar to scroll the li underneath a div. in which i made a ui, scroller, but client want the front and back arrow to adjust the slides. like regular scroll bar like browser.

please visit ; http://ikeafamilylive.com/stories/60

and you will witness what i request. And please don't recommend me a plug-in, because i need to use this scroll bar across the site with several customization process.

please give me the sample code / suggestion to make a scroll bar using jquery+css. with full functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery and css the best way to go is going with a plugin like JScrollPane:

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

If you want to have several customization and looks you can easily do so with this kind of plugin:
Example (different looks on the same page)
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html

Doing it by scratch will be a little more work, and you need good understanding of javascript and the framework you are going to use.

A plugin like JScrollPane will already have most of the functionality you will need, and if you need something that there isn't you can add the functionality using the basic plugin.

Comment: I already tried this. but i need to use both horizontal and vertical in same page. this plug-in is not working, if i use both scroll bar in single page. it is better to make one by manual then i can use wherever i need, thats why.. can you help me?

Comment: For this issue, any one help me?